# Passing variables from page to page using header();

Tags: php

Im Using the following code to validate (poorly, I know) a form's `$_POST[]`ed data. How can I pass `$auth` onto the new page so I can print it for the user? `(short of using my-account.php?auth=You Must......)`

```
if (!$_POST['supportarea'] || !$_POST['supportbody']) {

$auth = 'You must provide some information if we are ever to help you with your support ticket';
header('Location: ../pages/my-account.php');
}
```

Thanks. Alex.

Comment: don't use (!$_POST['foo']) since it will generate PHP errors.  Use (!isset($_POST['foo'])).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the session. In your script:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['flash'] = 'You must ...';
```

In the my-account.php script:

```
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION['flash'])) {
    $flash_message = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['flash']);
    unset($_SESSION['flash']);
} else {
    $flash_message = null;
}
```

Then, if `!empty($flash_message)`, show it to the user.